# Easy way to write servlet that returns table data in xml format

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

Easy way to write servlet that returns table data in xml format - ?

Data comes from a database table.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/WebRowSet.html

Comment: where does the data come from?

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TableServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("application/xml");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
        writer.println("<table>");
        writer.println("<style>");
        writer.println("<finish>polished</finish>");
        writer.println("<material>oak</material>");
        writer.println("</style>");
        writer.println("<legs>4</legs>");
        writer.println("</table>");
        writer.flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may found [jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) useful it works for XML, also supports JSON . Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html) (Look section 4) .